# How to hide unconnected nodes in ggraph

Tags: r, tidyverse, ggraph, tidygraph

Given the following example code,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

reprex <- tibble(to = 1:10,
                  from = c(2:10, 1),
                  facet = rep(1:2, each = 5)) %>%
    as_tbl_graph()

reprex_plot <- reprex %>%
    ggraph() +
    geom_node_point() +
    geom_edge_link()

reprex_plot + facet_edges(~ facet)
```

how can I hide the nodes that don't have an edge going into or coming out of the node?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't. I haven't been doing any network plotting lately, so I didn't really pursue it further

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the response. This would be hard to implement. I tried grid.arrange. I could remove isolated nodes but layout was different for each case. Not helpful. I think having an aesthetic in geom_edge_link() to show only connected nodes would be cool.

Comment: I think a partial solution would be to apply edge data to the nodes using something like
mutate(node_edge_description = .E()$edge_description), then facet by both nodes and edges...not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

reprex2 <- tibble(to = 1:10,
                 from = c(2:10, 1)) %>%
    as_tbl_graph() %>%
    activate(nodes) %>%
    mutate(facet = rep(1:2, each = 5))

reprex_plot <- reprex2 %>%
    ggraph() +
    geom_node_point() +
    geom_edge_link()  +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
    theme_graph() + 
    facet_nodes(~ facet)

reprex_plot
```

I can empathize with your approach, but difficulty arises with the intelligence of `tidygraph`'s `as_tbl_graph()`. You are passing it essentially an edge list where facet is a variable that only applies to the edges. You can verify this by doing `reprex %>% activate(nodes) %>% as_tibble()` to see that the facet column has no association with the nodes.

My solution is to construct the facet column explicitly on the nodes then use `facet_nodes()` which is the converse of `facet_edges()` in that

> Edges are drawn if their terminal nodes are both present in a panel.